# How can I Connect a postgres Database Inside Cloud9 IDE to Grafana and pgAdmin?

Tags: database, postgresql, grafana, pgadmin, cloud9-ide

I'm currently working within the Cloud9 IDE developer environment, and I've created a database inside it. Now, I'm trying to establish a connection between this database and both Grafana and pgAdmin. However, I'm facing some difficulties in obtaining the necessary address and configuring the connection correctly.

Here's what I've tried so far:
Localhost Connection: I initially attempted to connect using 'localhost' as the host address. Unfortunately, this approach didn't yield successful results.

Configuration Changes: I made several configuration changes to resolve the issue, but none of them seemed to work as expected.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or insights on how to successfully connect the database within the Cloud9 IDE to Grafana and pgAdmin. Additionally, if anyone has encountered similar challenges and found a solution, I'd love to hear about your experiences.

Thank you in advance for your assistance